# Found Nil Using Protocol in TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to update my model using data from a textField in a custom cell.  I set up a protocol in the cell's class and send the info to my ViewController, however I continually get "Found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value".  What am I missing? Thanks!

```
protocol UpdateDelegate {
   func didUpdate (someText: String)
}

class customTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   var updateDelegate: UpdateDelegate!

   @IBOutlet weak var someDescriptionField: UITextField!
   @IBAction func someDescriptionField(_ sender: UITextField) {
      updateDelegate.didUpdate(someText: sender.text ?? "") //error is here
   }
}

extension ViewController : UpdateDelegate  {
   func didUpdate (someText: String) {
      print(someText)
   }
 }

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate,  UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

//....

   viewDidLoad() {
      self.tableView.delegate = self
      self.tableView.dataSource = self
   }
}

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

   cell.someDescriptionField.text = meal.arrayOfPossibleDishes[indexPath.section].arrayOfSteps[indexPath.row-1].stepName
   cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
return cell
}
```

Comment: can you include the `cellForRowAt`, or otherwise where you actually create and configure the `customTableViewCell`?

Comment: Updated the cellForRowAt

Comment: UITextField action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple answer here: You are never setting the delegate on your cell.  Since your `ViewController` class conforms to your `UpdateDelegate` protocol you can update your `cellForRow` method like so:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
//set the delegate when setting up the cell
cell.updateDelegate = self
cell.someDescriptionField.text = meal.arrayOfPossibleDishes[indexPath.section].arrayOfSteps[indexPath.row-1].stepName
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
return cell
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought it must be something simple but have spent hours trying to figure it out.